# cannot access the Internet on my nokia lumia 920

Tags: wifi, internet

I changed my modem/router from Huawei to Linksys WAG320N recently. My lumia 920 says it's connected to my wifi at home but will not display any web pages. A search on the internet asked to check if the phone can see the new modem/router but typing in 192.168.1.1 for the setup page of the modem/router.
When I type in the IP address mentioned above, the phone always shows the setup page of my old modem/router and that's where I think the problem is.
I've tried restarting my phone as well as done a soft reset. Not tried a hard reset yet. Just wanted to exhaust all my options first. 
I need to refresh the page stored on my phone for when I type in 192.168.1.1.
Any suggestions?

Regards
Shajju

Comment: The problem isn't with your Lumia 920. You need to set up your router first and hence your phone keeps showing the router set up page. This question might me more suitable on [Super User SE](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: Does your new router use the same netblock as your old one?

Answer (score -1):

There are a range of issues that could be going on here, that may take a few attempts to identify and resolve all of the issues.

1. From your question, you are saying that when you type in the default IP address of your new router from your phone, you see the web page from your old router.

*This means that either you are still able to talk to the old router on the IP address that the new router should be using, or that your phone is showing a cached web page.  I'm guessing that your phone is still talking to the old router.*

If you have the old router still plugged in to the mains and your phone is connecting on the old wifi network then it would explain what you are experiencing.

Comment: I've seen something similar with a router that supports multiple VLANs, with devices being given DHCP renewals by the router for the "wrong" VLAN; In this situation the device only has cached copies of pages to use.